# amp-list not printing returned data from the connected JSON file

Tags: json, amp-html

I'm trying to implement amp-list to allow a different currency depending on where the user is from. I've implemented the amp-list element and created a JSON file (which is a CORS url), containing the data using the correct syntax.

The amp-list however is not printing the data, and instead printing a blank space. The HTML template is:

```
<amp-list width="auto"
  height="50"
  layout="fixed-height"
  src="/amp-price/57938">
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    <p class="price align-center {{test}}">{{price}}</p>
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

And the JSON response is:

```
{"items": [{"price": "\u00a321.59", "test": "test"}]}
```

But the rendered HTML is:

```
<amp-list width="auto" height="50" layout="fixed-height" src="/amp-price/57938" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed-height i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-layout" aria-live="polite" style="height: 50px;">
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    <p class="price"> - </p>
  </template>
<div class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content" role="list"></div></amp-list>
```

The JSON response has all the correct AMP headers, and I'm not getting any AMP errors in the console.

I've also followed the src link in the page source and it goes to the correct URL.

Is there something simple I'm missing?

Comment: Can you add a link to a sample page? One other thing: do you import the amp-mustache extension in the header?

Comment: @DHiskett check my answer hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I tried almost everything. The `amp-list` in safari 10 doesn't load the json endpoint.

But the solution for me is to add `credentials="include"` into my `amp-list` tag:

the final `amp-list`:

```
<amp-list credentials="include" id="smallcartsList" width="auto" height="@HeightRequest" [height]="CurrentCartList.items.length == 0 ? 5 : 50 * CurrentCartList.items.length" media="(max-width: 1199px)" layout="fixed-height" binding="no" src="/API/CartList/GetCartsList" [src]="cartlistsource" template="cartlistdetail"> </amp-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian Benz is correct I have use the same code and working fine

[**Here is working url**](https://jsfiddle.net/766u7apb/)

**HEAD JS**

```
<script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
```

**BODY HTML**

```
<amp-list width="auto"
  height="50"
  layout="fixed-height"
  src="https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/1f6f838d-25aa-11e8-8863-d99090d9ec78">
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    <p class="price align-center {{test}}">{{price}}</p>
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

[**JSON DATA LINK**](https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/1f6f838d-25aa-11e8-8863-d99090d9ec78)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm loading both amp-list and amp-mustache scripts in head, annoyingly my code is the same as in the jsfiddle but still doesn't seem to work. Unfortunately I can't share the page I'm trying this on as it's on our staging environment. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: may be url issue, it should be https

Comment: The URL is https (both the AMP page and the JSON URL). I tried changing it to an absolute URL also but no luck